# Reading data from Microsoft Band sudenly stops [Android]

Tags: android, android-service, android-sensors, android-bluetooth, microsoft-band

Inside an android Service I connect to the Microsoft Band 2 and read data from all the sensors.(I want to receive data even if the screen is locked).

However,  after a while I stop receiving any data (no more callback are called). Also, there is not event coming on the connection callback - where I should expect connection states changes to be signaled.

I should also mention that I am registering for all possible sensor events.

My code is similar to the one in the documentation examples, but I can provide snippets if useful (the documentation contains samples for connecting inside activities but it should work the same).

Has anybody encountered this issue or a similar behavior?

Comment: I have the exact same behaviour, about twenty minutes after the screen blanks the data listeners stop receiving data despite being on a Service with a thread and a wake lock. Still trying to figure out why.

Comment: Actually sorry to clarify that, if the listeners are on a Service running off the main UI thread they last about 20 minutes but if I but them in a thread then they last only a couple of minutes, same for you?

Comment: Yes, same behaviour. When registering for all events from inside a service, the listeners usually stop receiving data after 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably enable [WakeLock](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock). I had my MBand2 transfer realtime data (via a Service) throughout the day/night with no data loss or connection issues.